# Show that if $X \sim Bin(n, p)$, then $E|X - np| \le \sqrt{npq}.$

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, mean, expected-value, proof

Currently stuck on this, I know I should probably use the mean deviation of the binomial distribution but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV. While questions such as this are welcome, we do treat them differently - if you put more information into your question, you can get hints and guidance. Please see the relevant paragraph in [his page of the help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and the guidelines at the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please add the `self-study` tag and modify your question as suggested (that is, show what you've tried, or at least explain what you know about expectations and binomials) and identify where your difficulties lie.

Comment: you might also look at jensen's inequality

Comment: @seanv507 certainly, if we use Jensen's inequality, that does it in one step, and if thyde has covered it that's all that would be needed, but in this instance there's a really elementary proof that is well within reach of students who only know some very basic properties of expectation and variance.

Comment: $E[Y^2] = Var[Y] + E[Y]^2$ which becomes $Var[X] + (E[X] - np)^2$, then solving we get: $npq + (np - np)^2 = npq$.  Is this correct?

Comment: I have learned Jensen's inequality, but only in the context of convexity.  Could you possibly demonstrate it's applicability here?

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself with Var. just use E. you need to show that $E|X-np|\le \sqrt{E[|X-np|^2]}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So that the comment thread doesn't explode I'm collecting my hints toward a completely elementary proof (you can do it shorter than this but hopefully this makes each step intuitive). I've deleted most of my comments (which unfortunately leaves the comments looking a little disjointed).

1. Let $Y=X-np$. Note $E(Y)=0$. Show $\text{Var}(Y)=npq$. If you already know $\text{Var}(X)$, you could just state $\text{Var}(Y)$, since shifting by a constant does nothing to variance.
2. Let $Z=|Y|$. Write an obvious inequality in $\text{Var}(Z)$, expand $\text{Var}(Z)$ and use the previous result.  [You may want to slightly reorganize this into a clear proof, but I am attempting to motivate how to arrive at a proof, not just the final proof.]

That's all there is to it. It's 3 or 4 simple lines, using nothing more complicated than basic properties of variance and expectation (the only way the binomial comes into it at all is in giving the specific form of $E(X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ - you could prove the general case that the mean deviation is always $\leq \sigma$ just as readily).

[Alternatively, if you're familiar with Jensen's inequality, you can do it slightly more briefly.]

--

Now that some time has passed, I'll outline a little more detail about how to approach it:

Let $Z=|X-nq|$. Then $\text{Var}(Z)=E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2$, and $E(Z^2)=E[(X-nq)^2]$ ...

Note that variances must be positive. The result follows.